# Python - Run a script multiple times with different data

Tags: python

The script logs into a website (signin()) and then registers for an event (registerforevent()).

How do I make this script run multiple times and each time using a different email and password from a list to sign in and register?

Code:

```
import requests
import time
import random 

def signin():
    sess=requests.session()
    url = "https://www.DOMAINE.com"
    payload = {"username":email,"password":password}
    r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
    print(r.status_code)


def registerforevent():
    sess=requests.session()
    url2 = "https://www.DOMAINE.com"
    payload = {"username":email,"password":password}
    r = requests.post(url2,json=payload)
    print(r.status_code)

signin()
registerforevent()
```

Data file:

```
email1@email.com:Password123
email2@email.com:Password123
email3@email.com:Password123
email4@email.com:Password123
email5@email.com:Password123
```

Comment: There are several ways to to it: extend this program to open the text file with emails and passwords. Or extend it to get email and password as command line arguments, then loop over the credentials using the shell. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `signin()` and `registerforevent()` functions `email` and `password` arguments; for example:

```
def signin(email, password):
    ....

def registerforevent(email, password):
    ....
```

Then you can simply run your functions in a loop that iterates over your different emails and password pairs and input them into the functions. There are many ways to do such a loop and it will depend on how you are storing and accessing each unique email/password pair.

One example is if you had your credentials stored in a python dictionary where the key could be the email address and value the password, e.g:

```
credentials  = {"joe@blogs.com": 'password1234', "jane@blogs.com": '1234password'}

for email, password in credentials.items():
    signin(email, password)
    registerforevent(email, password)
```

Note: `credentials.items()` for python 3.x and `credentials.iteritems()` for python 2.x

Comment: The you for your comments - much appreciated, I am going to give this a try :)

Comment: No problem! If this has answered your question, please do mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need are some minor adjustments to your functions and a `for` loop. I won't explicitly give you the finished code, but here's the procedure:

Write `signin` and `registerforevent` such that they accept the address and the password as arguments. Loop over the lines in your file, split each line by `:` and call your two functions in each iteration. Pretty straight forward.

Alternatively, call your script from the command line with different `sys.args`.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I will look into what you have written and try get this sorted!